# Hardcoding URL in Spring

Tags: spring

```
package com.example.servingwebcontent;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Get your greeting <a href="/greeting">here</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The examples from the official guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

We can see that the url, that is greeting, is hardcoded.
Suppose, I write that url in 50 places. And now I want to change the url.

Is it somehow possible to escape hardcoding?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request can be GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, and PATCH.
To map the HTTP request with your definition, you need to use `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, `@PutMapping`, `@DeleteMapping`, and `@PatchMapping` in the controller class.

So, URL `/greeting` can be used in those 5 requests only. So, we can't write the same URL in 50 places in the controller class.

Comment: Pardon. I can't understand you. Can't I write 50 <a href="/greeting"> in a page? Can't I need that /greeting url in my Java code. For example to send it via email? The example is definitely a hardcode.

Comment: We can write 50 URLs or more on the view page and the same URL needs to be mapped in the Java code(Controller class) according to the HTTP request.

Comment: Clarify :  In View Page(JSP, Thymeleaf,etc), we can write the same URL `/greeting` to **any** times(50 or more). Java code (Controller class) doesn't know about the view page. So, In the Controller class, we need to map the URL `/greeting` to the method definition. So, the Java code will recognize the URL and implements the definition.